# How to create categories and subcategories system using Django?

Tags: django

How to create categories and subcategories system using Django?
Is there an application?

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is: https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/

And here is the documentation: http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/